# Redux find changes in prevState and currentState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am creating a crypto ticker App (using websocket form Socket.io) where I store all the crypto coin details in redux store.

The websocket gives me just the data of the coin whose value have changed, After receiving this data, I dispatch an action which update the redux store with that new value of coin.

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
    var socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
    var updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded]; //
    let refinedData = {}
     socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {  
      for (let i=0; i<updateCoinData.length; i++) {

        if (updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {  
          console.log(tradeMsg.coin)                      
        //Search for changed Crypto Value 

        updateCoinData[i]["perc"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["perc"]
        updateCoinData[i]['price'] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']['price']


        //Update the crypto Value state in Redux
        this.props.updateCrypto(updateCoinData);
        console.log("we are inside websocket")
          }
        }
     })
  }
```

For which I dispatch an action and then in reducer update the state like this

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case CRYPTO_FETCHING:
    return {
      ...state,
      itemsSomething: action.payload
    }
    case CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        itemsSucess: action.payload
      }
      case CRYPTO_DATA_FAIL:
      return {
      ...state,
      itemsFail: action.payload
    }
    case UPDATE_CRYPTO_DATA:
    return {
    ...state,
    itemsSucess: action.payload
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now, I want to highlight the coins whose value have changed (maybe make the text bold, or change the background) for which I need to compare my previous state with new state.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is is because reducers did not update the state correctly. `react` re renders only if there is a change in the state. As `updateCoinData` is an array, its better to use following code

`case REDUCER_TYPE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        array: action.array
      })`

You can use `componentWillReceiveProps`. This will execute if you get new `props` from `reducers`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ 
  if(this.props.property != nextProps.property){ 
     ///do what ever you want 
  } 
}
```

Comment: reducers changed the state correctly, React is rendering everything. My question is how can find and highlight the things which have changed in UI

Comment: You can use `componentWillReceiveProps`. This will execute if you get new `props` from reducers

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(this.props.property != nextProps.property){ 
       ///do what ever you want
     }
}`

Comment: Your comment solves my problem, Can you please include that in your answer so that I can mark it answered?